# Возможна ли перегрузка связей $_has_many в Kohana 3.2 ORM?

Tags: orm, kohana

Собственно код:

```
class Model_Language extends ORM
{

    protected $_has_many = array( 'supercategories' => array(
                                        'model' => 'supercategory',
                                        'foreign_key'=>'language_id',
                                        ));
    // get All Pages By Language Id
    public function PagesById($id)
    {
                    // overload
                    $this->_has_many = array( 'pages' => array(
                                        'model' => 'page',
                                        'foreign_key'=>'language_id',
                                        ));

        $language = ORM::factory('language',array('id'=>$id));

        if ($language->loaded())
        {

            $res = $language->pages->find_all();

            $pages = array();

            foreach ($res as $item)
            {
                $pages[] = array("id"=>$item->id, "name"=>$item->name, "url"=>$item->url, "content"=>$item->content);
            }

            return $pages;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

    }

}
```

Ну и естественно ошибка по этому поводу:

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: The pages property does not exist in the Model_Language class

MODPATH\orm\classes\kohana\orm.php [ 621 ]

616 
617             return $model->where($col, '=', $val);
618         }
619         else
620         {
621             throw new Kohana_Exception('The :property property does not exist in the :class class',
622                 array(':property' => $column, ':class' => get_class($this)));
623         }
624     }
625 
626     /**
```

Просто иногда мне нужно чтобы связь была с таблицей со страницами т.е. `pages`, а иногда с суперкатегориями `supercategories`, Эти две таблицы никак не взаимосвязаны, а вот предок 1, это таблица `languages`. Как в таком случае поступить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чем вас не устраивает такой вариант?

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'supercategories' => array(
        'model'      => 'supercategory',
        'foreign_key'=>'language_id',
    ),
    'pages' => array(
        'model'      => 'page',
        'foreign_key'=>'language_id',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Устраивает! Не знал просто я, не додумался вернее,... ох уж эти устаревшие туториалы :(

Comment: Странные у вас туториалы..